# Laravel give user access to specific route when conditions are met

Tags: laravel, routes, conditional-statements

Laravel 5

How to give user access to specific route when certain conditions are met?

For example let user access

```
Route::get(view('posts/{id}'),'PostsController@show');
```

when user has over 100 points in his user->points column.

Comment: create a middleware

Comment: See [authorized actions using polices](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization#authorizing-actions-using-policies) under laravel's authorization.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware) for this,In Laravel it is very easy to secure your routes by creating your own middlewares.

The following steps are required to do this:

1. `run command php artisan make:middleware Middlewarename` and you'll find your middleware inside  `app/Http/Middleware/yourcustomemiddleware.php`
2. Register your middleware in `app/Http/kernel.php` file which you just created
3. Now implement logic in middleware you just created:

YourMiddlewareClassCode:

```
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::user()->points >= 100)
    {

        return $next($request);
       
    }

    return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message','you are not allowed to access this');
}
```

4. Attach middleware to your route:

routes/web.php:

```
Route::get(view('posts/{id}'),'PostsController@show')->middleware('yourcustommiddleware');
```

All done now your route is secured.

**Summary:** this statement `return $next($request);` in middleware will return the route when condition is matched else it will redirect to the previous route.

**Note:** I don't know your db structure and also this is just an example to show you that what is middleware and how it works and how you can use it.